# SQL Pivot by Week Of date when week of dates are not Defined in the Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

The query below brings back the sum of course hours grouped by week. The issue is, the week values can be different every time they can not be defined in the query.  Here is an example of what is brought back in the query:

```
ID        Category      Week of   Total Hours
1111554 Case Management 7/2/2012     7
1111554 Case Management 7/9/2012     7
1111554 Case Management 7/16/2012       7
1111554 Pre-GED         7/2/2012    3
1111554 Pre-GED         7/9/2012    3
1111554 Pre-GED         7/16/2012   3
```

**QUERY**

```
WITH cteSource(DOP_ID, Category, WeekOf, [Hours])
AS (
    SELECT  DOP_ID,
         Category,
        DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, '19000101', [Date]) / 7 * 7 , '19000101') AS WeekOf, -- Monday
        [Hours]
    FROM    GW_PPP.dbo.SLAM_Attendence
)
SELECT      DOP_ID AS ID,
        Category,
        WeekOf AS [Week of],
        SUM([Hours]) AS [Total Hours]
FROM        cteSource
GROUP BY    DOP_ID,
        Category,
        WeekOf
ORDER BY    DOP_ID,
        Category,
        WeekOf;
```

Again, I can't figure out how to Pivot the table by not defining the weeks in the query

**SO not using something like this where the week of is defined:**

```
pivot
(

 week of in ([7/2/2012], [7/9/2012],
               [7/16/2012 ])
) piv
```

**I would also like to add a sum column by month if possible. Here is the output I would like:**

```
ID            Category  7/2/2012 7/9/2012 7/16/2012 July 12 Total
1111554 Case Management     7      7         7           21 
1111554 Pre-GED             3      3         3           12
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not know what the week values are going to be then you have to look at using dynamic SQL to get the result:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, '19000101', [Date]) / 7 * 7 , '19000101')) 
                    from GW_PPP.dbo.SLAM_Attendence
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT DOP_ID, Category, ' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
              SELECT  DOP_ID,
                   Category,
                  DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, ''19000101'', [Date]) / 7 * 7 , ''19000101'') AS WeekOf, -- Monday
                  [Hours]
              FROM    GW_PPP.dbo.SLAM_Attendence
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                SUM(hours)
                for weekof in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9793b/5)